# HTML/ Javascript: How to submit input and have it fill in a textarea with a submit/add more button

Tags: javascript, html, button, textarea

### So I am creating a pre-fill resume builder for a class and I want to have only one input area for career experience/ job info but I want a button that can be clicked over and over to submit each jobs information. Ideally the results would show in a textbox below it so they can see and keep track of what they have submitted.  I included the code I used on the HTML side:
**note: The entire page is basically one form with a submit at the bottom. This is a separate button.

### Edited:  So the idea is kind of just how submitting a StackOverflow Question works...as you type in the box, the results are shown below.  And then there is a form submit button.

Screenshot of the HTML page so far:

[image]

```html
<div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Work Experience</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="occupation">Job Title</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="occupation" name="occupation"><br>
      <label for="company">Company Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="company" name="company"><br>
      <label for="duties">Duties and Skills Attained:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="duties" name="duties"><br>
      <button type="button" id="generate">Add Work Eperience</button>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: your request is not clear dear

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I understand completely, but input names support arrays as well. So what you could do is something like this (assuming you want to have a submit for each entry).

```
<input type="text" id="occupation" name="experience[][occupation]" value="some-previous-occupation">
<input type="text" id="company" name="experience[][company]" value="some-previous-company">
```

You could then add hidden inputs to keep track of the ones that were already submitted (you could use a loop and replace `0` with the index of the loop)

```
<input type="hidden" id="occupation" name="experience[0][occupation]">
<input type="hidden" id="company" name="experience[0][company]">
```

This would then be submitted to your back-end like this:

```
[
    0 => ['occupation' => 'some-previous-occupation', 'company' => 'some-previous-company']
    1 => ['occupation' => 'developer', 'company' => 'stackoverflow']
]
```

Comment: "but input names support arrays as well" — Most systems which process forms don't need any special syntax for the names of fields to group the parsed data. You're making some assumptions about how the form is being processed that aren't supported by the question.

Comment: "assuming you want to have a submit for each entry" — The question explicitly said "I want to have only **one** input area"

Comment: @Quentin "assuming you want to have a submit for each entry" — What I meant here, is the OP asked for a solution where each new entry would need to be submitted. (As opposed to a solution where you would dynamically add inputs using JS)

My solution matches the provided screenshot in terms of amount of inputs. Since there's no back-end code provided and this is a HTML question, I would say my answer provides the info the OP is looking for (which is interpreted as: "How to handle a one-to-many-like relation in a form"